Calculus theorem
I was re-reading some old notes I took and I found this property written on it. However I don't manage to find this expression again on the internet, nor remember if it was true. May you help me find it if it is a valid expression?
\begin{equation}
    G(t) = \int_{a(t)= 0}^{b(t)}g(t,\tau)d\tau 
\end{equation}
Then:
\begin{equation}
    G'(t) = g(t,b(t)) + \int_{0}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}d\tau 
\end{equation}

This is just the chain rule for "nice" integrands.

This is called Leibniz integral rule. The proof is based on the chain rule and the derivation under the integral sign.

@SeanRoberson No, not really.

It is close to correct. The correct formula (often called the Leibniz rule) is
$$G'(t) = g(t,b(t))b'(t) + \int_0^{b(t)}\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,\tau)\,d\tau.$$
The first term is the analogue of the usual single-variable calculus application of the chain rule to differentiate
$$\int_a^{b(x)} g(t)\,dt$$
for a continuous function $g$ and differentiable function $b$.

Thanks You Ted, I forgot to mention that for my calculations b(t) = t - L with L a constant. In that specific case I think it's ok. And you're totally right regarding the expression
